# Как отобразить данные из выпадающего списка?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Всем добрый день. Прошу, подскажите пожалуйста, или натолкните на мысль как мне сделать так, что бы когда я выбирал нужную мне строчку в выпадающем списке, ниже отображалась (в моем случае) таблица из mysql. Читал что это можно сделать с помощью ajax, но увы, пока моих знаний не хватает чтобы написать такой скрипт. 
Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Что имею:

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SIM-manager</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <?php include 'test.php';?>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form name="form1">
            <p>Выберите таблицу:</p>
            <select name="tabs">
                <option value="1">SIM</option>
                <option value="2">Sim-base</option>    
            </select>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Open">
        </form>
        </div>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

ShowSIM.php

```html
<?php                           
include 'test.php';                           
   // Формируем запрос "Взять все записи" из таблицы с именем sim
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `sim`;";
   $result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>№</th>";
        echo "<th>LS_t</th>";
        echo "<th>LS_n</th>";
        echo "<th>Number</th>";
        echo "<th>ICCID</th>";
        echo "<th>Activate</th>";
        echo "<th>Deactivate</th>";
        echo "<th>Operator</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
     echo "<tbody>";
     echo "<tr>";
   // В цикле перебираем все записи таблицы и выводим их
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
   {
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['№'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['LS_t'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['LS_n'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['Number'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['ICCID'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['Activate'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['Deactivate'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['Operator'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
     echo "</tbody>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
```

ShowSimBase.php

```html
<?php                           
include 'test.php';                           
   // Формируем запрос "Взять все записи" из таблицы с именем simcards-base
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `simcards-base`;";
   $result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>№</th>";
        echo "<th>LS_t</th>";
        echo "<th>Number</th>";
        echo "<th>Date</th>";
        echo "<th>CardHolder</th>";
        echo "<th>Point Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Equipment ID</th>";
        echo "<th>Equipment Port</th>";
        echo "<th>IMEI</th>";
        echo "<th>Used</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
     echo "<tbody>";
     echo "<tr>";
   // В цикле перебираем все записи таблицы и выводим их
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
   {
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['№'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['LS_t'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['Number'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['Date'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['CardHolder'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['Point Name'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['Equipment ID'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['Equipment Port'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['IMEI'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['Used'];
       echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
```

В файле test.php содержится код подключения к базе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#tabs').on('change', function(){
    load_table();
});

function load_table(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "showBase.php",
        data: {
          tableName: $("#tabs").val()
        },
        success: function(table){
            $('#result').html(table);
        }
     });
}
```

Добавить id для select, к примеру id="tabs"
Добавить некоторый  ниже чем Ваш список выбора таблиц бд, куда будет вставляться Ваш html считываемой таблицы.

1. Делаем с использованием jQuery (так проще)
2. Обрабатываем событие onChange на select
3. При обработке с помощью Ajax запрашиваем данные из файла php, который должен отдать назад
4. В Ajax обрабатываем success, выводим данные в наш div id="result"
5. Два файла php который отдают таблицы объединям в один к примеру showBase.php, который будет принимать параметр, отвечающий за имя таблицы, и в зависимости от него выполнять запрос к нужной таблице.
6. Также в файлах php не делать каждый раз echo на каждой строке, а всё собирать в одну переменную, которую за один раз вывести (читай, отправить) обратно в переменную table при обработке success ajax

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за помощь. Если не сложно, у меня есть еще пара вопросов по поводу Вашего ответа.
1. Я не очень понял пункт 5. Какой параметр должен быть на странице showBase.php? Я думаю, может быть объявить переменную например $tab и сделать для нее if ($tab = 1) 
{ 
echo $result; // Т.е. выдать переменную в которой содержится вывод значений бд из таблицы например sim
} else {
echo $result1; //Т.е. выдать другую таблицу например simcards-Base
}
2. Не подскажите как объединить этот цикл в одну переменную, что бы не выводить через echo на каждой строчке?

Comment: while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {echo "<td>";echo $row['№'];echo "</td>";echo "<td>";echo $row['LS_t'];echo "</td>";echo "<td>";echo $row['LS_n'];echo "</td>";echo "<td>";
       echo $row['Number'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['ICCID'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['Activate'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['Deactivate'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo $row['Operator'];
       echo "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
     echo "</tbody>";}

Comment: Так, с выводом разобрался. Теперь интересно, как этот цикл присвоить переменной?
Как выводить данные используя только 1 echo (Может кому поможет):
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo '<td>'.$row['№'].'</td><td>'.$row['LS_t'].'</td><td>'.$row['LS_n'].'</td><td>'.$row['Number'].'</td><td>'.$row['ICCID'].'</td><td>'.$row['Activate'].'</td><td>'.$row['Deactivate'].'</td><td>'.$row['Operator'].'</td></tbody>';
}

Comment: перед циклом сделай переменную типа $html = ''; а в самом цикле делай $html .= 'новый текст' . newVar[i] . 'ещё что-то'; ну и после цикла у тебя получится твоя переменная $html имеющая всё то, что она насобирала в цикле

Comment: Что такое newVar[i]? И почему в $html .= ... Перед = стоит точка?
Пробовал и так и сяк, не получается. Я примерно понял что вы имели в виду, но когда я так делаю, все что находиться внутри присвоения переменной не работает, и соответственно я получаю не прогружающуюся страницу :(

Comment: Как этот кусок кода присвоить переменной $html, чтобы на выходе получилось исполнение этого кода в виде echo $html?
Код ниже.

Comment: include 'test.php'; $sql = "SELECT * FROM `sim`;";$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());$tableHead = "<table border='1'><thead><tr><th>№</th><th>LS_t</th><th>LS_n</th><th>Number</th><th>ICCID</th><th>Activate</th><th>Deactivate</th><th>Operator</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";echo $tableHead;while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){echo '<td>'.$row['№'].'</td><td>'.$row['LS_t'].'</td><td>'.$row['LS_n'].'</td><td>'.$row['Number'].'</td><td>'.$row['ICCID'].'</td><td>'.$row['Activate'].'</td><td>'.$row['Deactivate'].'</td><td>'.$row['Operator'].'</td></tbody>';}echo "</table>";